# Subistituir string por variavel

Tags: python, replace, number-format

eu tenho o seguinte texto dentro de um arquivo.txt

```
[ExpertSingle]
{
    1050 = N X 0
    1260 = N X 0
    1470 = N X 0
    1680 = N X 0
    1890 = N X 0
    2100 = N X 0
```

eu quero tranformar "X" em numeros usando random choice pra ficar assim

```
[ExpertSingle]
{
    1050 = N 2 0
    1260 = N 0 0
    1470 = N 4 0
    1680 = N 0 0
    1890 = N 1 0
    2100 = N 3 0
```

eu fiz esse codigo "copiei de varios videos q assisti"

```
import random
import fileinput

file_name = 'C:/Users/Felipe/Desktop/GH.txt'

c3 = (random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))

for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'X' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace('X','c3',1)
    print (line)
```

obtive esse resultado kkk

```
[ExpertSingle]

{

    1050 = N c3 0
    1260 = N c3 0
    1470 = N c3 0
    1680 = N c3 0
    1890 = N c3 0
    2100 = N c3 0
```

eu n sei onde errei e nao sei como chegar ao resultado desejado alguem pode me ajuda por favor?

Comment: Ao invés de usar o c3 como string, não seria o caso de colocar `line = line.replace('X',str(random.choice([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])),1)

Answer (score 1):

Nesta linha

```
line = line.replace('X','c3',1)
```

Você está substituindo `'X'` pela **string** `'c3'`, não pelo valor da variável `c3` como você deseja. Para acessar o valor de uma variável você não deve utilizar as aspas.

Provavelmente você adicionou as aspas porque quando tentou sem obteve o erro:

```
TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not int
```

E isso aconteceu porque o valor de `c3` é um inteiro, mas para substituir em uma *string* ele também precisa ser uma *string*. Para isso, faça `str(c3)`. Além disso, você está sorteando apenas um valor aleatório e utilizando-o em todas as linhas; pelo o que descreveu na pergunta parece que você quer que cada linha possua um valor aleatório diferente, então você precisará fazer o sorteio dentro do laço de repetição.

Comment: Omg funcionou mesmo muito obrigado, eu so nao entendi como fazer esse sorteio dentro do laco de repetição, como aplico isso no codigo?

Comment: @felipe Da mesma forma que fez, só que ao invés de deixar `c3 = random.choice(...)` fora do laço `for` você precisará colocá-lo dentro para que a cada iteração gerado sorteado um novo valor.

Comment: Tem razão deu certinho tudo q vc falou, muito obrigado mesmo

Answer (score 0):

assim ficou o codigo apos a ajuda dos amigos

```
import random
import fileinput

file_name = 'C:/Users/Felipe/Desktop/CHART.txt'


for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    c3 = (random.choice([0, 1, 0, 1]))
    if 'X' in line:
        line = line.rstrip()
        line = line.replace('X', str(c3),1)
    print (line)
```